# Store all regex related variables in one shot

Tags: regex, perl

### In short

How can I preserve regex variables such as `$+`, `$-`, `$&` or `$'` across the evaluation of another regex?

```
/(\w)\s(\w)/ # First regex
say "Found a b" if $1 =~ /b/;
say "$1, $2" # Match from the first regex
```

### In details

For a small [handlebars](/questions/tagged/handlebars) parser I would like to evaluate two cascaded [regex](/questions/tagged/regex). The first one identifies a tag and the second one gets the nature of the tag.

So I wrote this:

```
my $out = '';
while(/\{\{(?<tag>.*?)\}\}/g) {   
    if($+{tag} =~ /^\#(?<helper>\w+)\s+(?<parameters>.*)$/) {
        # Do something
    }

    $_ = $`.($data{$+{tag}} // $+{tag}).$';
}
```

In this particular case I want to use the result from the first regex after the execution of another regex which clobber the regexes variables (`$+`, `$-`, `$&`, `$'`, ...).

I know I can make this example use an intermediate storage like this below. However this is not the primary topic of this question.

```
push @regex, {match => $&, prematch => $`, #... 
};
```

> So, I am wondering if I can simply:
>
> 1. avoid the second regex to clobber the regex variables, or
> 2. save all the related regex variables in one shot?

I am not discussing the implementation or the method used here. Only the above question matters.

### For the curious only

Here is how I parse my [mustache](/questions/tagged/mustache) tags. The next step will be to parse helpers, lists and hash keys and keep everything as simple as possible...

```
my %data = ( name => 'John Doe', nick => 'Nikita', number => 42, );

$_ = do {local $/; <DATA>};
$_ = $`.($data{$+{tag}} // $+{tag}).$' while /\{\{(?<tag>.*?)\}\}/g;
say;

__DATA__
Hello {{name}}, how are you doing?
I know your nickname is {{nick}} your favorite number is {{number}}.
```

Comment: It's hard to figure out what you're doing. It looks like you're making something complicated out of something extremely simple. The dollar global vars, are, well global. Avoid using them. Also, if you need to control the pos() of a variable, that can be done as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Regexp::Result](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Result) captures `$1`, `$2`, `pos`, and all the good punctuation variables, and looks like exactly what you need. (It does not capture the inefficient punctuation variables `$&`, `$'` and dollar-backtick, because if you use them anywhere they will cause all your regexp matches to incur a performance penalty.)

For the `while` loop you may also find [Regexp::Flow](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Flow) useful depending on what exactly you end up doing in that loop. It creates the Regexp::Result objects for you and passes them into a coderef.

*Disclosure: I'm the author of both modules*

Instead of the three inefficient variables, if you need them, you can use `${^MATCH}`, `${^PREMATCH}`, `${^POSTMATCH}`, provided you use the `/p` flag when you execute your regular expression. Using Regexp::Result, you can get them with `$rr->match`, etc.

For completeness, if you just need the numbered captures and nothing else, [Data::Munge](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Munge) provides a function `submatches`.

Answer (score 3):

The regex variables are localized to the block they appear in, so just nest your second regex in a block:

```
$_ = 'b c';
/(\w)\s(\w)/; # First regex
{
    say "Found a b" if $1 =~ /b/;
}
say "$1, $2" # Match from the first regex
```

or, minimally, make it `...if do { $1 =~ /b/ };`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with handlebars, but it seems like your code would be simplified by using an optional non-capturing group:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

while (<DATA>) {
    my ($tag, $helper, $params) = $_ =~ /{{ (\w+) (?: \s+ (\w+) \s+ (\w+) )? }}/gx;

    say $helper if defined $helper;
    say $params if defined $params;
}

__DATA__
{{foo}}
{{foo bar baz}}
```

Comment: You might be right, but this is not the question :)

Comment: @nowox "So, I am wondering if I can simply: 1. avoid the second regex to clobber the regex variables, or..." I showed you how to do #1.

Comment: Well, I agree, you may have answered my first point. Actually this YAML example is bullshit, I just wanted to came across a simple example with to nested regexes.

Comment: @nowox If you're trying to solve a different problem, please show *that* problem, not some contrived example. The answer to your contrived example is "don't use `$\`` and friends because they're not necessary and over-complicate the code."

Comment: @nowox I still think this is an XY problem, but you can always localize the variables to a block: `perl -wE '$_ = "foo bar"; /foo/; { local $&; /bar/; say $& } say $&'`

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: unnecessary; see my answer